# What happened to rpm files in /usr/share doc?

Tags: fedora, rpm

Why does rpm list files for the statsd package that are not actually installed on the system?

```
[root@98f5b00e34c9 /]# rpm -ql statsd | grep /usr/share/doc/statsd\$                                                           
/usr/share/doc/statsd
[root@98f5b00e34c9 /]# test -d /usr/share/doc/statsd || echo Not there 
Not there
```

Note, this is not a result of the files being removed.  This is a clean docker image built from the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM fedora
RUN printf 'set editing-mode vi\nset keymap vi\n' > /etc/inputrc
RUN yum install -y statsd-0.7.2-8.fc26.noarch
CMD bash
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If main.tsflags in the yum configuration contains "nodocs" then the documentation won't have been installed in the first place.

Comment: And it is, for Fedora's base docker image.

Comment: This seems like a bug in `rpm -ql`, but I suppose it could be considered a feature.  It would be nice if `rpm -ql` gave an indication that the files are not actually installed.

Comment: `rpm -ql` only tells you what the package contains. If you want to find out the current state of the files then use `-V` or `-qs`.